# Manipulating a specific column from each data frame in a list

Tags: r, dataframe, list

I have a list that contains 35 dataframes. Each of those data frames have two columns, called "tth" and "counts". All columns are the same dimenssions, but have differnt values on each "tth". Here is the beggining of str() output of my list, called C2:

```
List of 35
 $ 100cm      :Classes ‘XY’ and 'data.frame':   8389 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ tth   : num [1:8389] 5.2 5.21 5.22 5.23 5.24 ...
  ..$ counts: num [1:8389] 1881 1830 1883 1836 1772 ...
 $ 102cm      :Classes ‘XY’ and 'data.frame':   8389 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ tth   : num [1:8389] 5 5.01 5.02 5.03 5.04 ...
  ..$ counts: num [1:8389] 2037 1994 2026 1950 1964 ...
 $ 103-Ooidscm:Classes ‘XY’ and 'data.frame':   8389 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ tth   : num [1:8389] 5.2 5.21 5.22 5.23 5.24 ...
  ..$ counts: num [1:8389] 2164 2249 2221 2250 2176 ...
 $ 103cm      :Classes ‘XY’ and 'data.frame':   8389 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ tth   : num [1:8389] 5.2 5.21 5.22 5.23 5.24 ...
  ..$ counts: num [1:8389] 1556 1448 1450 1521 1488 ...
```

Etc...

Now, before continuing with my data analysis, I need to do an extra step, which is adjustng the all the values from all the columns "tth" in all the dataframes of the list. This is a X-Ray diffraction (XRD) data, and I'm using a really useful R package called "powdR". Now, in that package, there is a function called tth_transform(), which will change the values of the the tth columns. the "tth" is a value of an angle provided by the XRD machine. Some machines can give results by using different X-Ray sources. Thus, the 2thetas (tth here) will differ depending on the source. My samples were analyzed with a Cobalt core, and I want to change it to Cupper values. The function provided by powdR does that. Here is an example from the package tutorial, created by Benjamin Butler and Steve Hillier:

```
#Create a multiXY object for this transform example
transform_eg <- as_multi_xy(list("Co" = xy_list1$D5000_1,
                                 "Cu" = soils$sandstone))

#Plot two patterns recorded using different wavelengths
plot(transform_eg,
     wavelength = "Cu",
     normalise = TRUE,
     interactive = FALSE)
```

[image]

```
#transform the 2theta of the "Co" sample to "Cu"
transform_eg$Co$tth <- tth_transform(transform_eg$Co$tth,
                                     from = 1.78897,
                                     to = 1.54056)

#Replot data after transformation
plot(transform_eg,
     wavelength = "Cu",
     normalise = TRUE,
     interactive = FALSE)
```

[image]

As you see, the tth values from the tth column of the Co dataframe change. I want to do this, but calling ALL the dataframes from my list. Any thoughts? Thanks!

I have being trying to use select() and laply(), but I'm a little rusty in R. Any help would be great. I'm sure this is not as complicated as I'm making it.

Comment: Do you need your data in lists, or can you join all of them in a single data frame using `bind.rows()` from the `dplyr` package?

Comment: Thank you for the recommendations, Jonathan. As it turns out, the package I'm using has a function that does this, so I figured it out. Thanks!